# "interactive-comments" option usage for Bash script

Tags: bash, set

I am wondering if it is possible to turn off the comment feature in noninteractive bash script.

Turning on or off "interactive_comments" or "interactive-comments" with `set` or `shopt` has no effect on the non-interactive shell.

Why did this happen? What is the point I'm missing?

Comment: Did you misinterpret "interactive_comments" (typo of dash for underscore) for "interactive"?

Comment: ... because it's actually `shopt ...` not `set...`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thank you very much, I will investigate `shopt`. Thank you for the answer. If you want to explain more, don't hesitate :)

Comment: I'm just trying to get to the core issue, and typo-fixes aren't terribly interesting. Please feel free to edit your Question to focus on what you're most confused by.

Comment: @JeffSchaller In fact, all I wonder is how to use the "interactive-comments" option on bash. I was just expecting to get an interactive shell using this(interactive-comments) option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was just expecting to get an interactive shell using this(interactive-comments) option.

Read the documentation instead of guessing.

> If set, allow a word beginning with `#` to cause that word and all remaining characters on that line to be ignored in an interactive shell

Turning on the option doesn't make the shell interactive. It controls whether `#` starts a comment if the shell is interactive, and has no effect if the shell isn't interactive.

Also,

> This option is enabled by default.

So turning it on has no effect.

Also, the documented way is `shopt -s interactive_comments` to turn it on and `shopt -u interactive_comments` to turn it off. But `set -o interactive-comments` and `set +o interactive-comments` are (undocumented, I think) alternatives.

---

You can only get an interactive shell if you start it as an interactive shell. There's no way to make a non-interactive shell interactive. Whether the shell is interactive or not depends on its command line and on whether it's running on a terminal:

- With the option `-i`, bash starts interactively.
- Without `-i` but with `-c` or with a script file name (`bash -c 'some command'` or `bash path/to/script`), bash starts non-interactively.
- Without `-i`, `-c` or a script file name, bash starts interactively if its standard input and standard error are both terminals, and non-interactively otherwise.

Regardless of the status of the `interactive_comments` option, comments in script files and in `-c` scripts are always recognized. The only case in which `#` at the start of a word doesn't start a comment is if the shell is interactive, the `interactive_comments` option has been turned off, and it's reading from standard input.

Try this `script.sh`:

```
# a comment
shopt interactive_comments
set +o interactive-comments
shopt interactive_comments
# another comment
```

Execution transcript:

```
bash-5.0$ # a comment
bash-5.0$ shopt interactive_comments
interactive_comments    on
bash-5.0$ set +o interactive-comments
bash-5.0$ shopt interactive_comments
interactive_comments    off
bash-5.0$ # another comment
bash: #: command not found
bash-5.0$ exit
```

Comment: Notice in *shopt* context it is `interactive_comments` (underscore), versus in *set* context it is `interactive-comments` (minus). The *Bash Reference Manual documentation* only mentions `interactive_comments` (at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Comments.html ). And [Bash developer/contributor/maintainer Chet Ramey once said](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-05/msg00002.html): "*[...] shopt is where it's supposed to be. The set option is there for backwards compatibility*".